# Ajax request with yahoo api does not work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, yql

Do someone have any idea why the following code fails

```
$(document).ready(function () {

doAjax("http://somedomain.com/page.aspx");
});

function doAjax(url) {
    if (url.match('^http')) {
        $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" +
            encodeURIComponent(url) +
            "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function (data) {
        if (data.results[0]) {

            var msg = 'success';
        } else {
            var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the widget.</p>';

        }
    }
  );
    }
}
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: call this page http://www.somedomain.com/page.aspx (I do not expect return any output)...only do request.

Answer (score 0):

the YQL format parameter needs to be set to json if you want it to return json.

Test your YQL here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

make sure it returns valid jsonp, then copy the url from the bottom and substitute your url.

Edit:

I guess one way to do it would be with an IFrame,

```
var iframe = $("<iframe src='" + yoururl + "' style='display: none;'></iframe>");
iframe.load(function(){
  alert('request sent');
  setTimeout(function(){
    iframe.remove();
  },10);
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: I do not want to return anything just call that page.

Comment: if it doesn't return proper json, the success callback will not fire.

Comment: However, the complete callback will fire. hmm...  If you don't expect return data, you don't need to hit YQL at all, as it will have the same result as making a jsonp request directly to the url.